# Dynamically save prefabs

Tags: unity

We have made different types of prefabs, if we want to change small thing in all prefabs, we do drag all those prefabs to scene ,create script which will do its required work .All is fine till now after that problem arises for saving those prefabs.We need to manually click "Apply" on all prefabs.

Has there anyway where we can dynamically use "Apply" feature via script?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround,use following code to do it so,

PrefabUtility.ReplacePrefab(gameObject, PrefabUtility.GetPrefabParent(gameObject), ReplacePrefabOptions.ConnectToPrefab);